# SlideDown divs until div with another class is found

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, hidden, slide

I have a code like this:

```
<div class="clickme">some text</div>
<div class="slide">slide</div>
<div class="slide">slide</div>
<div class="slide">slide</div>
<div class="clickme">some text</div>
<div class="slide">slide</div>
```

The divs with the class slide are hidden, what i want to do is that if the user clicks the div clickme, only the next three (or any number) of divs will slide down to display the content, the same if the user clicks the second clickme div.

I'm not able to change the html so I thought that jQuery could be my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eQLj8/)

```
$(".clickme").on("click", function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".clickme").slideToggle();
})​;
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, look at what happens when there are elements downstream from your click event: http://jsfiddle.net/eQLj8/1/

Comment: @TravisJ True, but I'm almost 100% sure that the OP has a wrapper for his accordion ( and according to the tags that's an accordion ) and this is not the case

Comment: Thank's for a really simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cvx9s/

*html*

```
<div class="clickme">some text</div>
<div class="slide">slide</div>
<div class="slide">slide</div>
<div class="slide">slide</div>
<div class="clickme">some text</div>
<div class="slide">slide</div>​
```

*js*

```
$('.slide').hide();
$('.clickme').click(function(){
 var tar = $(this).next();
 while(tar.hasClass('slide')){
  tar.slideToggle();
  tar = tar.next();       
 }
});
```

​

Comment: This solution also works correctly, i'll save this code for the future, thank's for your time.